# Wingpanel, adapt third party icons to background color

Tags: wingpanel, icons

When the background wallpaper is white, native wingpanel icons are black and when a window is maximized the icons are white because the background becomes black except with third party icons like deluge or dropbox.

I tried debugging to see how these icons become from black to white to try to fix with third party icons but I didn't see how.

Can anybody give me a solution to fix this issue? Is a theme or icon theme issue? Is it possible to fix the issue?

I need a clue please.

[image: Third party icons are white with the icon theme]
[image: Third party icons don't change]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This relies on a feature of Gtk+ that automatically colors icons ending in `-symbolic`. The applications in question would have to use this namespace in order to implement this feature, so it is a bug in those applications.